# How is the time defined with paths consistent with the idea that we assign time to frames?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In 49:34 of [this lecture](https://youtu.be/iFAxSEoj6Go?t=2974) by Frederic Schuller, it is explained that time is a derived quantity defined through this integral:

$$\tau =  \int_{\lambda_o}^{\lambda_1} \sqrt{ g(v_{\gamma}, v_{\gamma}) }$$

Where $g$ is the metric, the integral is done over a world line $\gamma$.

time is associated to world lines, but previously, I had learned that time is assigned to frame of reference in some special relativiy textbook. How do these two ideas relate?

Comment: Time is that which the clocks show. The formula is a description of what happens to a moving clock in spacetime with gravity. If you insert the trivial metric that describes a flat space, it gives you the simplified formula from special relativity. Either way, it's still about a clock. Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time? With regards to "frames", that concept becomes entirely local in general relativity. One can not extend it to a global reference frame any longer. What happens physically now depends on the path that an object, like a clock, takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time associated with a reference frame is the time measured by an observer (or  clock) that is stationary at the origin of that reference frame. In special relativity (but not in general relativity) we can extend that to a global time for all observers/clocks that are stationary with respect to that reference frame.

The time that Schuller is talking about is the proper time measured by an observer/clock that moves along the world line $\gamma(\lambda)$ between $\lambda=\lambda_1$ and $\lambda=\lambda_2$. This is a more general concept of time than the time associated with a given reference frame.